# QXmlQuery resume after error

Tags: xml, qt

I'd like to parse this page (http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) using this query
(//*[@id="downloadButton"]/@href) and this code:

```
QXmlResultItems out;
QXmlQuery xpath(QXmlQuery::XQuery10);
xpath.setQuery("doc('http://www.videolan.org/vlc/')//*[@id=\"downloadButton\"]/@href");
xpath.evaluateTo(&out);

QXmlItem item(out.next());
while (!item.isNull()) {
    qDebug()<<item.toAtomicValue().toString();
    item = out.next();
}
```

But all I get is a message saying this:

Error in http://www.videolan.org/vlc/, at line 151, column 65: Namespace prefix 'g' not declared.

which correspond, in the page source:

< g:plusone size="medium" href="http://www.videolan.org">< / g:plusone>

My question is: is there a way for QXmlQuery to resume after an error?

Comment: Maybe, but why not fix the error instead?

Comment: Because I do not own the webpage, I can't fix it.

Comment: In which line are you getting the error?

Comment: In the code? during evaluateTo. But my code is ok, see below.

Answer (score 0):

I got news directly from Qt about this issue. QXmlQuery is not made to parse HTML5 (see below). Back to QWebElement...

[image: Conversation with Qt]